# Idiom to describe a spoiled person

Tags: phrase-requests

What would be a good way to describe a person who is too spoiled and finds fault with everything she is offered? I keep thinking "she turns up her nose at everything" but turning up one's nose suggests disdain rather than displeasure/dislike. Many thanks to everyone who can help!

Comment: Not exactly the same but a synonym that is used a lot lately is 'entitled', meaning unaware of how spoiled they are.

Comment: Wait, aren't disdain and dislike similar enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be ***[spoiled rotten](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spoiled+rotten)*** may fit the context you describe:

> Fig. indulged in; greatly spoiled. *This kid is spoiled rotten! I was spoiled rotten when I was a child, so I'm used to this kind of wasteful luxury.*

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs)

Comment: Thanks very much everyone! These idioms are very useful. Yes, I was trying to avoid the "despise/disdain" connotation.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you just need to offer it on a "**silver spoon**". The idiom is commonly used to describe someone being so accustomed to "much better" from birth that they seem displeased with what you are offering them now.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/silver+spoon